# Como deixar o fundo do Visual Studio 2008 em tema escuro?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Utilizo o Visual Studio 2019 e gosto muito do tema escuro, porem ultimamente estou usando o 2008 por demandas do trabalho e ele tem o tema branco. É possível colocar ele no tema escuro ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Primeiro você tem que [baixar o tema WakeRoad Ink](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/wekeroad-ink)
2. Depois vá no seguinte caminho (o meu está em inglês) `Tools` > `Import & export settings`
3. Siga o assistente e pronto

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 4):

Você vai ter que baixar o tema neste site https://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian, la tem a opção para 2008, se quiser pode também criar seu tema.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]